# How to change angle when a ball collides with a rectangle?

Tags: javascript, math, collision-detection, trigonometry, angle

If a circle hits a rectangle and needs to bounce, I need to calculate its new direction.

This is what I have

```
    function tick() {
        var dx = Math.cos(ball.direction * (Math.PI / 180))*ball_md.speed;
        var dy = Math.sin(ball.direction * (Math.PI / 180))*ball_md.speed;
        ball.x += dx;
        ball.y -= dy;
        drawGame(); // refresh board

        //console.log(ball);

        paddles.some(function(paddle) {
            var circle={x:ball.x+ball_md.radius, y:ball.y+ball_md.radius, r:ball_md.radius};
            var rect={x:paddle.x, y:paddle.y, w:game_md.paddle.width, h:game_md.paddle.height};
            var hit = RectCircleColliding(circle, rect);

            if (hit) {
                if (Math.floor(ball.y) + ball_md.radius*2 <= paddle.y || Math.ceil(ball.y) >= paddle.y + game_md.paddle.height) { // hit on top or below paddle
                    ball.direction = 360 - ball.direction; 
                } else { // hit left or right side
                    ball.direction = 180 - ball.direction;  
                }
                return true;
            }
        });

        if (ball.y < 0 || ball.y+ball_md.radius*2 >= game_md.height) { // hit top or bottom wall
            ball.direction = 360 - ball.direction; 
        }
        if (ball.x < 0 || ball.x+ball_md.radius*2 >= game_md.width) { // hit left or right wall
            ball.direction = 180 - ball.direction;   
        }
    }
```

but it doesn't seem to always work. Does anyone know why?

Cases when it fails. In this case, it zigzags really fast on the paddle surface.

[image]

DEMO: https://jsfiddle.net/3ok2farw/2/

Comment: I would log every bounce and see if there's a pattern to when it doesn't work.

Comment: `but it doesn't seem to always work.` What is it doing currently, and what should it do instead?

Comment: It fails when it hit corners.

Comment: I added an example of it failing.

Comment: Add your integrator code.  If you aren't moving your ball back to the collision position and re-integrating with reflected direction from *that* point, the ball is probably wiggling back and forth continuously reversing its direction because it never actually escapes the wall/paddle.

Comment: added more code

Comment: Added a jsfiddle to demo the issue. It happens half a sec after it runs.

Comment: It's odd that people often use a polar representation of the velocity, when a vector-based approach avoids constantly having to deal with the singularity at 360 degrees (and using `sin/cos`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to treat the corner collision separately. When it hits the corner the velocity of the ball doesn't change perpendicular to either the horizontal or vertical axis, but along the line connecting the center of the ball and the corner. I'm adding a drawing to make it a bit clearer. If the collision is perfectly elastic (no energy loss), then the `v_normal` component gets replaced by its negative, `-v_normal`. If the collision is perfectly plastic (maximum energy loss), the exit velocity is just `v_tangential`. Hope this helps!

[image: corner collision diagram]